# Why does ReLu activation not work on my data?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am training a neural network using tensorflow. I am trying to use the tf.nn.relu as my activation function but the network just won't learn. If I scale my data between 0-1 and use the sigmoid it learn perfectly fine. I understand that my relu function might just have died instantly. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

**Setup:**

```
layer_1 = tf.layers.dense(tf_x, neurons_no, tf.nn.relu)
... # all other hidden + output layers in similar way

loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate, global_step, decay_steps, decay_rate, staircase=True)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
```

**Why I want to use relu and not sigmoid:** since the "normal" range of my data is not between 0-1, I would prefer an activation function not limited by that range.

**How my data looks like:** 
Regressional setup:
3 input values: x1, x2, x3. Range between 0-0.3
1 output value: y. Range unknown, but 0 or greater (e.g. 50, 517, 2001 etc)

Sample graph along one x-dimension:
[image: x1]

Comment: Did you try different base learning rates? Also I advance to try `tf.train.AdamOptimizer` instead `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer`

Comment: Are you using already using a batch normalization layer? If not, have you tried normalizing the data to have mean 0, variance 1?

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I changed to the AdamOptimizer and continuously decreased the learning rate and at some point it just worked. Could you shortly elaborate why you would advice to use the AdamOptimizer? A link with explanation would also suffice.